# What is the setCompression() equivalent in GraphicsMagick?

Tags: php, pecl, graphicsmagick, gmagick

[The php.net ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) has setCompression() and setCompressionQuality().

[The php.net GraphicsMagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php) shows no compression methods listed at all. However, [this changelog](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=gmagick) shows that setCompressionQuality() was added in 1.0.8b3 and predefined compression constants are listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/gmagick.constants.php).

What is the setCompression() equivalent for GraphicsMagick? I'm trying to output a lossless jpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file `gmagick_methods.c` does not contain an implementation for `setCompression`. It appears to only have `setCompressionQuality` implemented.

It looks like it was requested at one point and rejected.

> [2010-06-19 04:15 UTC] vito@php.net
>
> setImage, getImage and
>   getImageGeometry had been added to Gmagick. The other functions will
>   not be included, consistent with the GraphicsMagick API.

via https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59166

However, there does appear to be a [compression type option in the API](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/types.html#compressiontype) ([also, available in the utility](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-compress)) so I'm not sure when that was added. Maybe you could try reopening the bug?

Comment: I don't know C, but this looks like setCompressionQuality() to me. My question is specific to setCompression(). As in, http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setcompression.php, to set the **type**.

Comment: Sorry about that. Looked into it again and updated my answers with my findings.

Comment: @Isius did my answer help at all?